# How install C/C++ plugin to Netbeans (linux)

Tags: c++, c, linux, netbeans, installation

I'm trying to install C/C++ plugin on linux Mint on Netbeans IDE.

But I cannot do it by tools->plugin->download because of my proxy server.
I've downloaded it from netbeans website, but it comes with the .sh format and Netbeans only read .nbm files. Simply nothing appens.

How can I install C/C++ plugin on Netbeans without that tool of downloading from within?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure netbeans around your proxy server like this:

Tools > Options > General in the IDE, select Manual Proxy Settings, enter the HTTP Proxy and Port for your proxy

If you don't know how to find these information about your proxy:

firefox>tools>options>advanced>>network>settings
then you 'll find them in.

With that you will be able to install c/c++ with the provided installer.

Comment: The problem is that I use Wifi Fon Zon, a free wifi network. So I dont have a proxy name. I just know I use port 8080. Isn't there another way of doing it?